# fastest way to stream image over web-socket

Tags: websocket, gorilla

i'm trying to broadcast a image to any client that connect to websocket, the problem is : something the speed aren't enough to achieve 10FPS+

```
// img are from ~11ms process
png.Encode(&b, img)
// jpeg.Encode(&b, img, nil)

sEnc := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(b.Bytes())
message := Message{
    Type:   "frame",
    Frame:  sEnc,
    Device: "pap99",
    Width:  320,
    Height: 240,
}

encoded, _ := json.Marshal(message)

err = c.WriteMessage(websocket.BinaryMessage, encoded)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("write:", err)
    return
}
```

the client :

```
conn.onmessage = function (evt) {
     var data = JSON.parse(evt.data);
     frame.src = `data:image/png;base64,${data["frame"]}`
}
```

is there any way to achieve 10FPS+ with current code ? thankyou

Comment: PNG encoding is typically slow - what about JPEG? What does 11ms mean? Do you run the image capture, processing, PNG encoding, base64 encoding and sending on a single thread? Definitely consider multithreading/multiprocessing.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes; and inside infinity loop; because gorilla/websocket doesn't support concurent send